# Linux Manjaro sending full screen signal all time

Tags: linux, drivers, xorg, manjaro

For some strange reason, my Manjaro started to act abnormal.

First, randomly, it sends full screen signal in loop to my active window, like holding F11. The image below shows what is happening.

[image: current state]

I can stop it by pressing F11 multiple times from an external keyboard, but it starts again few minutes later. There is no regular interval, but it can be from 1 to 2 minutes.

Second, the touchpad died, not responding, not listed when running  `dmesg`, `libinput list-devices` and `xinput --list`.

Also, some keys of the laptop's keyboard are not answering, like F11 or the combination lshift + p. However, when I run `xev` command to scan pressed keys, all them are listed, including lshift + p.

You could say that my hardware is malfunctioning, but if I use a live ISO from a sd card, all is working.

I have no clue what is causing it, but my guess is related to xorg.

My current system:

```
$ inxi --admin --verbosity=7 --filter --no-host --width
System:
  Kernel: 5.12.19-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.1.0
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.12-x86_64
  root=UUID=2ac4c4a5-5f31-4100-9370-3146a89847b4 rw quiet apparmor=1
  security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3
  Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 vt: 7
  dm: GDM 40.1, LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: SAMSUNG
  product: 500R4K/500R5H/5400RK/501R5H/5500RH/500R5S v: P08RDD
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 9 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: SAMSUNG model: NP500R5H-XD1BR v: SGL8623A06-C01-G002-S0001+10.0.10586
  serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: P08RDD.171.160427.CL
  date: 04/27/2016
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 16.8 Wh (98.2%) condition: 17.1/43.1 Wh (39.7%)
  volts: 12.5 min: 11.4 model: SAMSUNG Electronics SR Real Battery
  type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Unknown cycles: 174
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_2 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse serial: <filter>
  charge: 55% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes status: Discharging
  Device-2: hidpp_battery_3 model: Logitech Wireless Keyboard K540/K545
  serial: <filter> charge: 100% (should be ignored) rechargeable: yes
  status: Discharging
Memory:
  RAM: total: 7.67 GiB used: 2.72 GiB (35.4%)
  RAM Report: permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required.
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-5200U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
  arch: Broadwell family: 6 model-id: 3D (61) stepping: 4 microcode: 2F cache:
  L2: 3 MiB bogomips: 17567
  Speed: 1499 MHz min/max: 500/2700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1499 2: 1508
  3: 798 4: 2165
  Flags: 3dnowprefetch abm acpi adx aes aperfmperf apic arat arch_perfmon avx
  avx2 bmi1 bmi2 bts clflush cmov constant_tsc cpuid cpuid_fault cx16 cx8 de
  ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts epb ept ept_ad erms est f16c flexpriority flush_l1d
  fma fpu fsgsbase fxsr ht ibpb ibrs ida intel_pt invpcid invpcid_single
  lahf_lm lm mca mce md_clear mmx monitor movbe msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl nx
  pae pat pbe pcid pclmulqdq pdcm pdpe1gb pebs pge pln pni popcnt pse pse36
  pti pts rdrand rdseed rdtscp rep_good sdbg sep smap smep ss ssbd sse sse2
  sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 stibp syscall tm tm2 tpr_shadow tsc tsc_adjust
  tsc_deadline_timer vme vmx vnmi vpid x2apic xsave xsaveopt xtopology xtpr
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled
  Type: l1tf
  mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI
  Type: spec_store_bypass
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Type: spectre_v1
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional,
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Samsung Co driver: i915 v: kernel
  bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:1616 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M] vendor: Samsung Co driver: nvidia
  v: 470.63.01 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm bus-ID: 03:00.0
  chip-ID: 10de:1347 class-ID: 0302
  Device-3: Silicon Motion ATIV VGA Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  bus-ID: 2-5:4 chip-ID: 2232:1069 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.13 compositor: marco v: 1.26.0 driver:
  loaded: intel,nvidia resolution: <missing: xdpyinfo>
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.3
  direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Samsung Co driver: snd_hda_intel
  v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:160c class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Samsung Co
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:9ca0
  class-ID: 0403
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.12.19-1-MANJARO running: yes
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.19 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.38 running: no
Network:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: Samsung Co driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.0
  chip-ID: 168c:0042 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global
  broadcast: <filter>
  IP v6: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global
  IP v6: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global
  IP v6: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: link
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
  vendor: Samsung Co driver: r8169 v: kernel port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
  chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IP v4: <filter> scope: global broadcast: <filter>
  WAN IP: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 2-4:3
  chip-ID: 0cf3:e360 class-ID: e001
  Report: bt-adapter ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
Logical:
  Message: No logical block device data found.
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found.
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 447.13 GiB used: 112.37 GiB (25.1%)
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: SanDisk model: Ultra II 480GB
  size: 447.13 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s
  type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 00RL scheme: GPT
  Message: No optical or floppy data found.
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 372.53 GiB size: 365.68 GiB (98.16%)
  used: 112.37 GiB (30.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1 label: N/A
  uuid: 2ac4c4a5-5f31-4100-9370-3146a89847b4
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 513 MiB size: 512 MiB (99.80%)
  used: 312 KiB (0.1%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2 label: N/A
  uuid: FD0E-9EB9
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 7.45 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
  dev: /dev/sda4 maj-min: 8:4 label: N/A
  uuid: 0331c07a-eca4-4868-9e30-46b2a7e3ad20
Unmounted:
  ID-1: /dev/sda5 maj-min: 8:5 size: 16 MiB fs: <superuser required>
  label: N/A uuid: N/A
  ID-2: /dev/sda6 maj-min: 8:6 size: 66.11 GiB fs: ntfs label: N/A
  uuid: AA0ECDF30ECDB899
  ID-3: /dev/sda7 maj-min: 8:7 size: 533 MiB fs: ntfs label: N/A
  uuid: 027C2DA87C2D9785
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-2: 1-1:2 info: Intel Integrated Hub ports: 8 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s
  chip-ID: 8087:8001 class-ID: 0900
  Hub-3: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 11 rev: 2.0
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 2-2:6 info: Logitech Unifying Receiver type: Keyboard,Mouse,HID
  driver: logitech-djreceiver,usbhid interfaces: 3 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s
  power: 98mA chip-ID: 046d:c52b class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: 2-4:3 info: Qualcomm Atheros type: Bluetooth driver: btusb
  interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s power: 100mA chip-ID: 0cf3:e360
  class-ID: e001
  Device-3: 2-5:4 info: Silicon Motion ATIV VGA Camera type: Video
  driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 2 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 500mA
  chip-ID: 2232:1069 class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter>
  Device-4: 2-8:5 info: Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
  type: <vendor specific> driver: rtsx_usb,rtsx_usb_ms,rtsx_usb_sdmmc
  interfaces: 1 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s power: 500mA chip-ID: 0bda:0129
  class-ID: ff00 serial: <filter>
  Hub-4: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 4 rev: 3.0 speed: 5 Gb/s
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0003 class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: 49.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 199 Uptime: 17m wakeups: 13 Init: systemd v: 249 tool: systemctl
  Compilers: gcc: 11.1.0 clang: 12.0.1 Packages: pacman: 1440 lib: 426
  Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 running-in: terminator inxi: 3.3.08
```

Comment: Try in a live session. If the problems persists it's hardware, obviously.

Comment: Yes, in live session all work as I said. Also, boot setup has mouse support, which works with the touchpad. It's something when loading the system, kernel or driver. I would need to debug, but I'm not sure which commands should be used and what should be searched.

Comment: If the same happens in a live session it's HARDWARE.